# ArcMap 10.7 Python Label Expression - compound. expression verified but will not label. Syntax issues

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, python-parser

I have road ID labels in a string field that need to be parsed down. I'm using the python advanced label expression. I've removed the preceding '0s' successfully as well as some known text.

I need to remove all other preceding alpha characters prior (left of) to the number but keep any alpha characters after (right of) the number. The amount of characters vary so I can not use [:3] etc.

This code snippet removes ALL alpha, not just at beginning:

[image]

This snippet shows verified but does not yield any labels:

[image]

What is your syntax suggestion?

I've also tried lstrip()[0].isalpha() can't get that to work either.

Answer (score 1):

A recursive solution might work. Something like:

```
def FindLabel(label):
    if label[0].isalpha():
        FindLabel(label[1:])
    return label
```

Which would be called with `FindLabel([ID])`

Comment: I got the syntax correct by adding label = ( [ID] ) and it verifies but no labels are returned.                                def FindLabel ( [ID] ):
    label = ( [ID] )
    if label[0].isalpha():
        FindLabel([ID][1:])

Comment: UPDATE:  I've got the label syntax to work correctly but ONLY for the letter 'A'   new syntax is:                                                                           def FindLabel ( [ID] ):
    label = ( [ID] )
    if label[0].isalpha():
        return [ID].lstrip('A - Z')